# BabylonJS: How to set background color transparent

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I'm struggeling with making the background color of a babylonjs scene transparent.
Since I'm using a .glb file i need to add a environment. Before using the defaultEnvironment i was able to remove the background color with `scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color4(0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0)` now.. after using `const helper = scene.createDefaultEnvironment();` I found no posibility to remove the background color anymore.

```
  // Create a basic BJS Scene object
  var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine)
  const helper = scene.createDefaultEnvironment();
  helper.setMainColor(new BABYLON.Color4(0, 0, 0, 0));
  // scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color4(0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the default environment ([`createDefaultEnvironment`](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/classes/BABYLON.Scene#createDefaultEnvironment)), use the optional [`createGround`](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/interfaces/BABYLON.IEnvironmentHelperOptions#createGround) and [`createSkybox`](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/interfaces/BABYLON.IEnvironmentHelperOptions#createSkybox) properties to specify whether the ground and skybox should be drawn:

```js
var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine)
const helper = scene.createDefaultEnvironment({
    createGround: true,
    createSkybox: true,
});
scene.clearColor = new BABYLON.Color4(0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0);
```